# How to display input values from textfields with array name attributes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form which should submit data, but before submission I want the user to have a preview of what they have filled before clicking on the submit button.

The JavaScript function I have put in place, only shows input values from only one of the textfield.

what I expect was that for each textfield I would get its input values displayed.

Currently, I am getting just one value from the textfields with this same id.

How can I adjust my code to show value of each textfield .

```js
// function and element to view input value
function myFunction() {
  var Milstonedescription =
    document.getElementById("milstanedetails").value;
  document.getElementById("Milestonesdescriptionvalue").innerHTML =
    Milstonedescription;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="milstone" id="milstanedetails" placeholder="Describe the milestone or task you will complete"  oninput="myFunction()" name="milestone[]">

<input type="text" class="milstone" id="milstanedetails" placeholder="Describe the milestone or task you will complete"  oninput="myFunction()" name="milestone[]">

<p class="halffieldcontainer" id="Milestonesdescriptionvalue"></p>
```

Comment: You are not using `name`, you are using `Id`

Comment: `oninput="myFunction(this)"` using `function myFunction(Milstonedescription ) {
      var description = Milstonedescription.value;
      document.getElementById("Milestonesdescriptionvalue").innerHTML =
        description;
    }`

Comment: and also, you have two `id` for two different elements, that's not valid HTML, `id` is unique for each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem on your code is that you use the same id on multiple input field, thats not possible because id are unique and whatever you will get only the first element with the matching id.

If you want to get your value from each fields you should use getElementsByClassName('className') and looping on, it's seems to correspond to what you want to do.

EDIT :

Yeah last version didn't work properly, i edited and tested that one. Seems to work properly on my side now. ( http://jsfiddle.net/tgo46se2/ )

```
     function myFunction() {
   let milstones = document.getElementsByClassName("milstone");
   let milstoneDescription = '';
   for(let i = 0; i < milstones.length; ++i) {
        milstoneDescription += milstones[i].value;
   }
   document.getElementById("Milestonesdescriptionvalue").innerHTML = milstoneDescription;
}
```

Comment: this did not work, please did you test this before giving me

Comment: pls put on codepen or jsfiddle pls still does nt work here

Comment: please how do i display the inputs on different lines, thanks

Comment: depending on how you want to display it, i have made something to make them as list with li ( https://jsfiddle.net/Ultima/f307utz2/9/ )

Answer (score 0):

this could works:

```
    <!doctype html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p id="text"></p>
    <input type="text" class="milstone" id="milstanedetails" placeholder="Describe the milestone or task you will complete"  oninput="myFunction('milstanedetails','Milestonesdescriptionvalue')" name="milestone[]">

<input type="text" class="milstone" id="milstanedetails2" placeholder="Describe the milestone or task you will complete"  oninput="myFunction('milstanedetails2', 'Milestonesdescriptionvalue')" name="milestone[]">

<p class="halffieldcontainer" id="Milestonesdescriptionvalue"></p>
</body>
<script>
    // function and element to view input value
function myFunction(idEl, idPrev) {
  var Milstonedescription =
    document.getElementById(idEl).value;
  document.getElementById(idPrev).innerHTML =
    Milstonedescription;
}

</script>
</html>
```

I change the second id because in html id must be unique.

I hope this help

Comment: yea i know this works, but in my situation, i am adding my texfields dynamically to the form, so it could b 1,2 or even 5. thats why the textfields in the question i posted have the same ids and classes. i just used the question to explain

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to make each input id unique because using the same id value for multiple elements is not valid in HTML.

you can achieve what you want by this code:

```js
function myFunction(){
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("[name='milestone[]']");
  var input_value1 = nodes[0].value;
  var input_value2 = nodes[1].value;
  var text = '';
  if(input_value1 && input_value1 !== ''){
    text += 'first input value: ' + input_value1;
  }
  if(input_value2 && input_value2 !== ''){
    text += '<br /> second input value: ' + input_value2;
  }
  document.getElementById("Milestonesdescriptionvalue").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="milstone" id="milstanedetails1" placeholder="Describe the milestone or task you will complete"  oninput="myFunction()" name="milestone[]">

<input type="text" class="milstone" id="milstanedetails2" placeholder="Describe the milestone or task you will complete"  oninput="myFunction()" name="milestone[]">

<p class="halffieldcontainer" id="Milestonesdescriptionvalue"></p>
```

and here is a [working snippet.](https://plnkr.co/edit/MoOdymLxXcvzMaQ5YzMP?p=preview)

Comment: in my scenario the fields are added to the form onclick of a button thats problem here and thats why the fields are using same ids

Comment: sorry but i am not getting what you said!
do you mean how to get each input value?

Comment: i suggest you to write the whole code or create a snippet supported with comments so we can help you with the problem

Answer (score 0):

Get inputs by class attribute.

```
function myFunction() {
    var milstones = document.getElementsByClassName("milstone");
    var milstoneDescription = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < milstones.length; i++) {
        var val = milstones[i].value;

        if (typeof val != "undefined")
            milstoneDescription += val + ' ';
    }

    document.getElementById("Milestonesdescriptionvalue").innerHTML = milstoneDescription;
}
```